# Sum a set of numeric columns and collapse string column by group

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lapply

Suppose I have a data frame (df) like this:

```
    Names ID Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 Thing5
1:  Gen1 id1    10     5    10     5      10
2:  Gen2 id2     1     2     3     4       5
3:  Gen1 id3    10     5    10     5      10
4:  Gen2 id4     1     2     3     4       5
5:  Gen3 id5     7     7     7     7       7
```

For each 'Names', I would like to sum 'Thing' columns, and collapse the strings in 'ID':

```
   Names   ID     Thing1  Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 Thing5
1:  Gen1 id1|id3    20      10     20     10    20
2:  Gen2 id2|id4     2       4      6      8    10
3:  Gen3 id5         7       7      7      7     7
```

I am able to achieve this via dplyr:

```
df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(Names)%>%
        summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse='|')),matches('^\\D+$'))


df2 <- df %>%
         group_by(Names)%>%
           summarise_each(funs(sum = sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with('Thing' )) 

bind_cols(df1, df2[-1])
```

However, this solution takes very long since I have a data frame with more than 10k rows and more than 10k column!

Is there any possible solution with `data.table`?

The closest I have gotten is this here:

```
> setDT(df)[, c(paste(df$ID,collapse = "-", sep = ""), lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE)), 
            by = Names, .SDcols = !"ID"]

   Names                     Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 Thing5
1:  Gen1 id1-id2-id3-id4-id5     20     10     20     10     20
2:  Gen2 id1-id2-id3-id4-id5      2      4      6      8     10
3:  Gen3 id1-id2-id3-id4-id5      7      7      7      7      7
```

Obviously this is not what I am going for since it will collapse all IDs and not just the ones that were aggregated by summarizing via "Names".

I would very much appreciate your help!

Here is the example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Names = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen1", "Gen2","Gen3"),
                      ID=c("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5"),
                      Thing1 = c(10L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 7L), 
                      Thing2 = c(5L, 2L, 5L, 2L,7L), 
                      Thing3 = c(10L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 7L), 
                      Thing4 = c(5L, 4L, 5L,4L, 7L), 
                      Thing5 = c(10L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 7L)), 
                      .Names = c("Names","ID","Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3", "Thing4", "Thing5"),
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1:5L))
```

Comment: Related: [Apply different functions to different sets of columns by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273072/apply-different-functions-to-different-sets-of-columns-by-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't heavily rely on `data.table` you could use `aggregate` two times and `merge` the results.

```
merge(aggregate(.~Names, df[-2], sum), aggregate(ID ~ Names, df, paste, collapse="|"))
#   Names Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 Thing5      ID
# 1  Gen1     20     10     20     10     20 id1|id3
# 2  Gen2      2      4      6      8     10 id2|id4
# 3  Gen3      7      7      7      7      7     id5
```

Comment: Thank you Jay! Like this solution as well. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse) 
df %>% 
  group_by(Names) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.character), str_c, collapse = "|"),
            across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  Names ID      Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 Thing5
  <chr> <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 Gen1  id1|id3     20     10     20     10     20
2 Gen2  id2|id4      2      4      6      8     10
3 Gen3  id5
```

use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- copy(df)
setDT(dt)
  
out_sum <- dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Names, .SDcols=!"ID"] 
out_id <- dt[, list(id = sapply(list(ID), paste0, collapse = "|")), by = Names]  
merge(out_id, out_sum)

   Names      id Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 Thing5
1:  Gen1 id1|id3     20     10     20     10     20
2:  Gen2 id2|id4      2      4      6      8     10
3:  Gen3     id5      7      7      7      7      7
```

Comment: I am glad to help! If the answer was helpful, you can accept it.